# Manage uploads folder to year based only (no month)

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress there is this option for managing attachments.

> Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders

```
./2014/10/image.png
```

Is it possible to drop the month, only use the year? Possibly to set it up in `wp-config.php` or theme `functions.php` etc.

```
./2014/image.png
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In wp-config.php, you can set a custom uploads location:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/myimages' );
```

For your situation, pass it a variable for the current year - something like:

```
$year = date( 'Y' );
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/' . $year );
```

Uncheck the "Organize my uploads..." so it's not creating subdirectories in there as well.